# Shazam Api Data Processing

Tags: javascript, c#, api, asp.net-core, signalr

site.js file

```
 "use strict";
    
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/radioHub").build();
    

     
        function processData(  ) {
        fetch("https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/songs/detect", {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "text/plain",
            "x-rapidapi-host": "shazam.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "1ab???"
        },
        "body": "Generate one on your own for testing and send the body with the content-type as text/plain"
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        
        }



document.getElementById("radioPlayer").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveRadio", function (radio, shazam) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("songNameList").appendChild(li);
     
    li.textContent = `${radio} return ${shazam}`;

     


 });

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("radioPlayer").disabled = true;
    var radio = document.getElementById("radioPlayer").value;
    var shazam = processData();
    console.log(shazam)
    connection.invoke("SendRadio", radio, shazam).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Hub.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRCoreServer.Hubs
{
    public class ViewHub : Hub

    {
        public async Task SendRadio(string radio ,string shazam)
        {
             await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveRadio",radio, shazam);
        }  
    }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@page
    <div class="radio-container">
        <div class="radio-header">
        </div>
        <div class="radio-body">
            <div class="shine"></div>
            <div class="current-song">
                current song
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">  </div>
                <audio  id="radioPlayer"  src="https://us4.internet-radio.com/proxy/douglassinclair?mp=/stream;" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
    
     
            </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

In order to learn the names of the songs playing on the radio, I try to send data to shazam api using the signalR library.
There are hub.cs site.js and index.cshtml files.

(null return null)
result on screen.

it can play song but i couldn't send it to shazam correctly.
What should I do to get the right results?

Comment: Please check your code: ` var shazam = processData();`, in the `connection.start().then` function, you will calling the processData() method, but from the processData() method, we can see that it just using fetch method to execute a post request and will not return data. So, the `shazam` might be null. You can refer to the [JavaScript Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) and [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: <live_stream_config xmlns="http://provisioningplayer/livestream-1.9" version="1.9">
<mountpoints>
<mountpoint>
<status>
<status-code>200</status-code>
<status-message>OK</status-message>
</status>
<transports>
<transport>http</transport>
</transports>              xml file starts like this .Contains information such as ip, port

Comment: I found out i need to read radio data from xml file, and I need to send the radio data to the page with signalr. Thanks a lot for the help.I don't know how to send the xml file. xml file should be streamed.@Zhi Lv